# apple watch app conflict uiview extension

Tags: ios, uiview, watchkit

I've tried to add a AppleWatch App to my own app.But I got a error says: **Cannot find interface declaration for 'UIView'**,pointed to a file in which i define an extension for UIView,Which looks like below(I've add import UIKit/UIKit.h> code in pch file:

```
UIView+KKFrameExtension.h
@interface UIView (KKFrameExtension)
@property (nonatomic,assign) CGFloat  width;
@property (nonatomic,assign) CGFloat  height;
@property (nonatomic,assign) CGFloat  x;
@end

UIView+KKFrameExtension.m
-(CGFloat)width{
return self.frame.size.width;
}

-(void)setWidth:(CGFloat)width{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size.width = width;
    self.frame = frame;
}

// height
-(CGFloat)height{
    return self.frame.size.height;
}

-(void)setHeight:(CGFloat)height{
    CGRect frame = self.frame;
    frame.size.height = height;
    self.frame = frame;
}
```

but if I delete my WatchApp,everything goes well,so what happened,what should I do?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WatchKit does not use UIViews.  Nor does it use UIViewControllers.  It uses WKInterfaceControllers.  Generally, UI is created in the watch app storyboard, so you'll have to create what you want there.  When you created your watch targets, you should have gotten targets for a watch app and a watch extension.  The storyboard will be in the watch app (in fact, that's about all it has), and the code to manipulate it will be in the watch extension.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.Maybe I didn't discribe well.My problem is,I have got a well-working project which contain only one tartget for iPhone.Then I add a watch app target to this project.When I tried to compile my ORIGINAL IPHONE TARGET(not newly added watch target),It brokes,but I've done nothing to this target.This make me very confused.

Comment: Is your watch app target trying to compile this extension file?